# putting a table values in datagridview filtered by date

Tags: c#, date, gridview, datatable

using ado.net and trying to filter a gridview by date but keep getting Error.

```
string query1 = $"Select * from buy Where [date] >= {dmy} and [date] < {dmyplus}";
            SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConnetionPath4);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query1, connection1);
            DataTable data1 = new DataTable();
            adapter1.Fill(data1);
```

by the way dmy and dmyplus is
var dmy="'2021/21/11'"
var dmyplus="'2021/22/11'"

My Error is "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Comment: is the dmy and dmyplus a string or a datetime variable?

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: dmy and dmyplus are string

Comment: i know about injection attacks i am just building this app as a collage project and security does not matter in this case

Comment: @FranzGleichmann

Comment: @Steven .......

Comment: @benyamindashtestani ***especially*** in a college project it matters. because when you're learning it _the wrong way_, you will most likely ***do*** it the wrong way. there is ***no reason*** to ever _not_ use parameterised statements. and security is not everything. as i mentioned, parameterised statements help prevent about 90% of SQL errors i see on stackoverflow - ***very probably yours included***, _and_ they potentially improve performance. TL;DR: _just use them._

Answer (score 0):

HI i finally Cracked the code

My mistake was in dmy and dmyplus.they was like yy-dd-mm.
simply put date in them in this syntax yy-mm-dd.And it solved my problem.
God I tryed Almost Everything before this.
I was working on it from 8 AM and its 5 PM now.
Thanks For Helping by the way.

Comment: i don't want to nitpick - but _exactly this_ would never have happened with parameterised statements.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes i know i tried that too but i received whole another error and i know using parameters would be better and safer but that was not necessary for me because in my form user is not going to be able to write anything and the whole operation is automatic so i was not worried about sql injection. but still im grateful for your advice.thank you